# All app icons not showing up in my home screen

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, launcher

I have a Spice Mi-429 which I bought a few days ago. Since I was not an android user before buying this phone, I am unable to understand some features of the phone.

This phone is Android Kitkat 4.4, 1Ghz Processor, 512MB RAM, 4GB ROM.

Currently I am unable to set the icon shortcut of apps in home screen. Apps like Hangouts, YouTube, GMail are not showing up on the Home screen since they are already installed. I have to go to App Manager > All Apps > YouTube > Launch them.

Can anyone help me with it???

Here are the screenshots of my phone..

[image: Homescreen] [image: App manager] [image: App info] [image: YouTube]

<sup>Click images for larger versions</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the apps on the homescreens in Android are to all intents and purposes shortcuts, and not the apps themselves.

You **should** but don't have an icon in your dock (the lowermost part of the homescreen) that opens this app drawer.

The icon usually looks a bit like this:

http://cs3-1.4pda.to/4714358.png

[This image](http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Android-4.4-KitKat-launcher.jpg) shows: Google Now, then your homescreen, note the middle icon on the bottom, and then the App Drawer opened (very right of image). This is the list of all your applications.

You could try (I don't have a similar device) long pressing on a free part of a homescreen and see if you can add an action, or shortcut to the app drawer.

Alternatively a launcher like [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) or indeed [Google's own "Google Now Launcher"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en) are free and have this option.

Here is an example of adding an action in Nova Launcher which might help point you in the right direction (note **app drawer**):

[image]

Comment: Hi their, thanks for the reply, yes your answer is right in that sense but in my phone it shows no icon like that, in fact all app shortcuts are embedded in homescreen only and i am using a default android launcher...

Comment: @SaurabhLP it's not a default android launcher it's spices version of one and is recommend replacing it. Nova launcher and others are far superior, try a few they're mostly free!

Comment: yes you were right, its a launcher issue, i have downloaded GoogleNow Launcher, its shown that icon, thanks for the answer...

Comment: @SaurabhLP Great, glad to hear it's working! I like the Google Now launcher, then dislike it, then like it again! I've always been a fan of Nova but I do like the Now integration in Google's launcher. Great thing is they are mostly free!

Answer (score 1):

I do not like the App-drwaer that came with my phone,so started using Google Now Launcher.After installing you may have to set up your apps/widgets on homescreen again, but it's quite simple using the round center button.
Note: After installing, I had to *clear cache* on my current browser before launching this.